# Moongodb-PHP:How to upsert the new record in the existing document

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Hi i am working on mongodb php. I am inserting data into existing document with following method

```
    array_push($BookingArray, array(
    "booking_id" => $booking_id,
    "startdate" => $startdate,
    "enddate" => $startdate, 
    "starttime" => $starttime,
    "endtime" => $endtime));

$talent['bookings'] = $BookingArray;
$mongoDb->save($talent);
```

Problem is when i am saving for the first time then the record is getting properly inserted but when the second recored for the second time i want to add into "bookings" part then it is updating the previous record of booking with new values.

I dont want that. When the second record arrives that should be added to bookings providing no change to previous record. How to upsert the record using mongodb php????

I want the data to be saved in this format

```
    ..upper content(assume)...
     }
    }
  },
  "bookings": [
  {
  "booking_id": "5492985664363d880200002a",
  "startdate": "12/01/2014",
  "enddate": "12/01/2014",
  "starttime": "12:30am",
  "endtime": "2:00am"
 },
       {
  "booking_id": "5192285664363f880200002a",
  "startdate": "13/01/2014",
  "enddate": "14/01/2014",
  "starttime": "11:30am",
  "endtime": "2:30am"
 }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data that you tried to upload.

Comment: i hav updated my question with the data of my Umongo client database. I want that when data with new booking id comes the previous data should not be updated. instead it should be added next to the previous one...

Comment: right now it is updating my previous one

Answer (score 1):

So You are trying to insert the same doccument again but with the only difference that it have an extra value in bookings array?

Be aware that this is not the most optimal thing to do(unless you have to do it like this).

Anyways, the problem is that $talent["_id"] is already in the db, so when you do a save() it will update the previous document.

What you should do is an

```
insert()
```

but before you need to remove the _id field from $talent, because you can not insert two doccuments with the same _id in mongo, for this you can do an

```
unset($talent["_id"])
```

**Edit:**

Then the problem is in the php side. Check if the array_push() is doing what you want it to do.

I would do like this:

```
$new_booking = array(
"booking_id" => $booking_id,
"startdate" => $startdate,
"enddate" => $startdate, 
"starttime" => $starttime,
"endtime" => $endtime);

BookingArray[] = $new_booking;
```

Also you migth try with the following sintax instead

```
$mongoDb->update(array('_id'=>$talent["_id"]),array('$set'=>array('bookings'=>$BookingArray)),array('$upsert'=>true));
```

Comment: no my friend i think you havent read my question carefully. I want to have multiple records with different booking_id to be inserted in bookings array. One talent can have no. of bookings so the booking_id field is the _id of booking for which he has applied. If talent applies to three bookings then booking_id of all three bookings should be there inside bokings array.

Comment: right now i hav again edited my question you can see the format i expect

Answer (score 0):

Use [insert()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php) instead of [save()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.save.php). Save does an upsert:

> If the object is from the database, update the existing database
> object, otherwise insert this object.